# Reading Identity Users Information From EF in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have extended the default asp.net core identity user like so:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public MyObject SomeObject { get; set; }
    public List<Email> AssociatedEmails { get; set; }
}
```

It seems that all user data is stored in a table called `AspNetusers` but there is no definition for this in the ApplicationDbContext so i can't reference it in my code.

I need to be able to read various users details from Entity Framework and also associate users records with various other entities so i need to be able to access the user entity through EF.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`ApplicationDbContext` is an `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`, you can write your own IdentityDbContext

```
public class YourApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<YourApplicationUser>
{
    public YourApplicationDbContext (DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

and use it in your startup class

```
services.AddDbContext<YourApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

services.AddIdentity<YourApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<YourApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```